# Distance between centroid and farthest point of polygon

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, mapinfo

I have a village polygon layer which has more than 6,00,000 records.
I have calculated centroid of each village.
I want to find the distance between centroid and the farthest node of each polygon.
Check the image below for reference. Black lines are polygon boundaries.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: interesting... I just did this friday with postgis to produce a circle around a polygon.  I need a few minutes to look for the code I used.. 

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/EKnkg.png

Comment: First we might need to know wich programs you have at your disposal. Also how did you create thoses centroids and nodes? (Even if it seems a bit obvious that the nodes on the polygons are the ones used to set the boundaries of your shapes, but did you add aditionnal point on top of thoses?)

Comment: Is the location of the centroid important? How did you create them?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133099/select-the-most-distant-vertex-from-polygons-centroid-using-arcpy/133122#133122

Comment: If the centroid truly is central, then it's the radius of the smallest circle centred on that point that fits the polygon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)

Comment: @MoreauColin I didn't calculate nodes. It's a functionality in MapInfo that displays the nodes. I want to know how to calculate the nodes. Centroids I calculated using MapInfo

Comment: @GISGe Yes centroid is important. I want distance from Centroid to a boundary node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are working with MapInfo. The "Distance Calculator" (find it in tool manager) has many options and I think it can handle this task too. There is an article about it here: http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-jul-2013/Toolbox-Distance-Calculator

Answer (score 15):

Using PostGIS, I used ST_ConvexHull to simplify the polygon for a faster result:

Get the furthest Point:

```
SELECT Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom as FarPoint from (
SELECT ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom)),
generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom))))) as points, 
geom
FROM Villages_v4_Trial_region
ORDER BY ST_MaxDistance(points,ST_Centroid(Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom)) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And if you are interested in creating a Circle from the centroid:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(Center,ST_Distance(Center,FarPoint)) as Circle
FROM (
SELECT Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom as FarPoint, Center from (
    SELECT ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom)),
    generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom))))) as points,
    ST_Centroid(Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom) as Center, 
    geom
    FROM Villages_v4_Trial_region
    ) as Villages_v4_Trial_region
    ORDER BY ST_MaxDistance(points,Center) DESC
    LIMIT 1) as foo;
```

[image]

Comment: Simple, fast, efficient. Thank you for posting this because this'll help me too in what i am working on right now.

Comment: @kttii I don't know how to use PostGIS. Can you provide a simpler solution, in arc or mapinfo or qgis

Comment: @kttii So I installed Postgresql. I copy-pasted this exact query but it gave an ERROR:  column "the_geom" does not exist. What do I do?

Comment: the_geom should be replaced by your geometry field name.  You would have to put your data into PostgreSQL as well.  PostgreSQL is a database like MSSQL.  PostGIS is an extension to make the database spatially aware and provide all the ST_ functions.

Comment: @kttii I updated the field name from the_geom to "gid" in my database. After running the query again, I got this ERROR:  function st_convexhull(integer) does not exist

Comment: @Divya gid (an integer) is not the same as geom (a geometry string).  The error is telling you that there is not a function called ST_Convexhull that takes in an integer.  ST_Convexhull will either accept a raster field or a geometry field.  What is the name of your table and the field names in your table?

Comment: Hi @kttii I have added a screenshot of field names in my table.
I ran this query now:
`SELECT ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(public.Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom)),Generate_Series(1, ST_NPoints(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(public.Villages_v4_Trial_region.geom))))) as FarPoint FROM public.Villages_v4_Trial_region`


It showed this error:

**ERROR:  relation "public.villages_v4_trial_region" does not exist
LINE 1: ...llages_v4_Trial_region.geom))))) as FarPoint FROM public.Vil...**

_This is my table name: public."Villages_v4_Trial_region"_

Comment: @Divya can you provide a screenshot of your data?  I'm interested in your geometry column, as it should look something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/nVY6d.png

Comment: @kttii Please check the screenshot I've added.

Comment: I modified the statement to match your data/table names and I removed generate_series since it was necessary for this case.  see if  that produces anything.  I see now that I need to modify it again because it gets the last point rather than the farthest which happens to be both for my geometries.  I'll update it again in a bit.

Comment: @Divya try the updated answer please.

Answer (score 4):

Using next **PyQGIS** code:

```
from math import sqrt

layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

n = len(feats)

centroids = [ feat.geometry().centroid().asPoint() for feat in feats ]
polygons = [ feat.geometry().asPolygon()[0] for feat in feats ]

lengths = []

for i, pol in enumerate(polygons):
    max_dist = 0
    idx_j = 0
    for j, point in enumerate(pol):
        dist = sqrt(centroids[i].sqrDist(point))
        if dist > max_dist:
            max_dist = dist
            idx_j = j
    print i, idx_j, max_dist
    lengths.append([centroids[i], pol[idx_j]])

crs = layer.crs()
epsg = crs.postgisSrid()

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'max_distance',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(n) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(lengths[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

and this shapefile (with 11 features):

[image]

I got a memory layer where polylines were the distance between centroid and farthest point of each polygon (feature); as it can be observed at the next image:

[image]

At the Python Console of QGIS, it was also printed the index of feature, the index of point in feature where distance from centroid is a maximum and, finally, maximum distance.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to use PyQGIS. Can you provide a simpler solution, in arc or mapinfo or qgis

Comment: Try this link for help with getting started with PyQgis  http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you're using MapInfo, here is a MapBasic function I wrote a while back for an in-house tool I was working on. It takes a source node (your centroid point) and a region object (the polygon) as arguments and returns a point object at the furthest node in the polygon from the source point.

```vb
Function GetFurthest(ByVal oNode1 as Object, ByVal oObj as Object) as Object

Dim sourceE,sourceN,East,North,Longest,Dist as Float,
    nNodes,nPolys,i,j as SmallInt,
    oNode2 as Object

    sourceE = CentroidX(oNode1)
    sourceN = CentroidY(oNode1)
    Longest = 0

    nPolys = ObjectInfo(oObj,OBJ_INFO_NPOLYGONS)
    For i = 1 to nPolys
        nNodes = ObjectInfo(oObj,OBJ_INFO_NPOLYGONS+nPolys)
        For j = 1 to nNodes
            East = ObjectNodeX(oObj,i,j)
            North = ObjectNodeY(oObj,i,j)
            Dist = Distance(sourceE,sourceN,East,North,"m")
            If Dist > Longest then
                Longest = Dist
                oNode2 = CreatePoint(East,North)
            End if
        Next
    Next

    GetFurthest = oNode2

End Function
```